# What causes the files in the vendor directory in a docker container to update?

Tags: docker

I downloaded an image (https://hub.docker.com/r/roundcube/roundcubemail/) and ran it. The resulting container has a directory at `/var/www/html`. Inside this directory, is a `vendor` directory.

I made a git branch at `/var/www/html`. After a day or so, I ran `git status` and noticed a bunch of files in the `vendor` directory had changed. I did not change them myself.

I'm not sure what the vendor directory is or does and I have no idea what I could have done to trigger those files to update. Can someone clue me in?

I'm assuming it's safe for me to add `vendor` to .gitignore.

Comment: Can you add info about the image that you downloaded?

Comment: Sure thing. It has been added to the OP.

Comment: I think it has something to do with composer, not docker. I don't have a clue about composer, either.